# Fitch natural deduction proof of ∀x∀y∀z((S(x,y) ∧ S(y,z)) → S(x,z)), ∀x¬S(x,x) ⊢ ∀x∀y (S(x,y) → ¬S(y,x))

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I'm trying to prove this sequent but I keep getting stuck. Working with multiple variables as well as quantifiers is confusing me quite a bit. My effort so far is below - you will see that I am trying to get to the proof on line 12 (through lines 7 to 11), but I am not sure how to deduce that with the give combination of variables. I am aware that section 8 to 10 does not make sense - I am just trying to use all the premises that were provided, but I'm not sure where that part fits in.

As you can see, I am replacing variables x, y and z with concrete values a, b and c respectively. I don't know if I am interpreting this incorrectly though.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something obvious here - any help will be appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I think I just figured it out - it seems like you can name your variables as you wish - you don't have to use different concrete values for different variables. My solution is below:

[image]

Can someone please just double check my logic?

Thanks!

Comment: If a (reliable) proof checker tells you that your proof is correct, every human being must agree. In particular, I and you. Anyway, what you wrote is exactly the proof that I would write, even before the introduction of proof checkers.

Comment: Yes, a universal quantifier can be eliminated to any extant term, including ones you've used before.  For all means for all after all.  So you may instantiate $\forall z$ to term $a$.

Comment: Thanks all - yes I figured that questioning the validity of a reliable proof checker is rather pointless...but thanks for confirming! Still learning but I am making progress.